# Google Address Bar Search in own form

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, firefox

i try to build a browser start page and wanted to ask, if there is a possibility to auto jump to the address bar with an input field like the google search does.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using the javascript `focus()` method

`document.getElementById('#inputID').focus();`